# Unable to get text from div when text includes <span>

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath

I am using Selenium with Java.I am unable to get a text from span tag, every time returns an empty string.
HTML code:

```html
<div class="fade-repeat-animation alert ng-isolate-scope alert-error" ng-class="type && "alert-" + type" ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="alert.type" close="closeAlert($index)">
    <button class="close" ng-click="close()" type="button" ng-show="closeable">×</button>
    <div ng-transclude="">
        <span class="ng-scope ng-binding">This text</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the Selenium code:

```
String ipError = within(secs(10)).div(By.xpath("//div[@class='fade-repeat-animation alert ng-isolate-scope alert-error']/div/span")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

I tried use also `getText()` and `getAttribute("textContent")` but always returns empty `String`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to try with `getText()` method, try this code

```
String Spantext=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='ng-scope ng-binding']")).getText();
System.out.println(Spantext);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This code really helped me! Everything working fine)

Answer (score 0):

May be because of angularJS Webdriver is not able to read text from UI.
Try to use this code and let me know if it worked or not.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".fade-repeat-animation.alert.ng-isolate-scope .alert-error")).getText();
```

Comment: Unfortunately not helped. "Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException"

Answer (score 0):

As per the `HTML` you have provided to print the text **`This text`** you can use the following line of code :

```
System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='fade-repeat-animation alert ng-isolate-scope alert-error']//div/span[@class='ng-scope ng-binding']"))).getAttribute("innerHTML"));
```